# Flutter package with static ios framework and cloud_firestore package

Tags: ios, cocoapods, flutter-plugin, podspec, xcframework

I am working on Flutter package which depends on static ios framework as `spec.dependency 'static-pod', '~> 1.0.0'` in podspec

When I'm using my package in project with `use_modular_headers!` everything works fine. But when I'm trying to add `cloud_firestore` package I'm getting this issue:

```
Error (Xcode): module map file '/Users/me/projects/flutter-project/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found
```

If I try to add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` I'm getting next error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'plugin-Swift.h' file not found
/Users/me/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/plugin-1.4.7/ios/Classes/MyPlugin.m:1:8
```

In my ios/Classes directory next structure:

- MyPlugin.h
- MyPlugin.m
- SwiftMyPlugin.swift

And full plugin podspec file:

```
require 'yaml'

pubspec = YAML.load_file(File.join('..', 'pubspec.yaml'))

Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name             = pubspec['name']
  spec.version          = pubspec['version']
  spec.summary          = 'My Flutter plugin.'
  spec.description      = pubspec['description']
  spec.homepage         = pubspec['homepage']
  spec.license          = { :type => 'MIT License', :file => '../LICENSE' }
  spec.author           = 'me@gmail.com'
  spec.source           = { :path => '.' }

  spec.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  spec.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'

  spec.platform = :ios, '14.0'
  spec.dependency 'Flutter'
  spec.dependency 'static-pod', '~> 1.0.0'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  spec.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`use_modular_headers!` does not work with Firestore. Details in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3816.

Firestore, as well as all of recent Firebase product versions, should be integrated with `use_frameworks!` or `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`.